# Displaying 1 post from a particular catergory if selected in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to make a loop in wordpress that pulls in 1 post from 1 category when selected, But if not it should display the latest post from the custom post type I'm calling. e.g Testimonials, Latest News, Case Studies.

Here is what I have, do I need an ifelse; statement to query if the cat doesn't exist then display the latest post in that CPT.

Here is the code I have.

```
  <?php
                $query = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonial&catergory_name=home&showposts=1&paged=' . $paged);
                $postcount = 0;
            ?>
            <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $postcount++; ?>
                    <li> 
                     <A HREF="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></A>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                the_post_thumbnail('thumb-casestudy');
                            }else {
                            ?>
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                            <?php } ?>
 </a>
                        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                        <p class="hm_text"><?php 
                                //the_excerpt(); 
                                echo get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'wpld_cf_home_page_text', true) 
                        ?></p>




                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please, write again step by step what You would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly:

```
$query->post_count
```

should allow You to check if there are any post returned by query, and if not, than You can call another query.